# How do I reorder UITableView cells in Realm Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I'm using **Realm** for my Note-taking-app.
I used core data before and I am now migrating core data to realm, but i got trouble! reordering objects like this causes error.

```
do {  
let realm = try Realm()
let source = myNote[sour!.row]        
try realm.write() {
 myNote.remove(objectAtIndex: sourceIndexPath!.row)
 myNote.insert(source, at: destensionIndexPath!.row)
 }
 }
 catch {
 print("handle error")
 }
```

So I added
**orderPosition** property to my object

```
dynamic var orderPosition: Int = 0
```

and changed *tableView moveRowAtIndexPath* to this
 [ReorderingRealmResultsInTableView.swift](https://gist.github.com/kishikawakatsumi/cc4a1f32fb8ee34eb509d54027d731b5)

but it didn't helped a lot.
so How can I **reorder objects** in realm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd encourage you to store ordered items in a [`List`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html) rather than sorting based on an `orderPosition` property.

Storing the index manually will be much less performant when moving an item, because all objects between the "old index" and "new index" will need to be mutated to account for the change.

You can then use [`List.move(from:to:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift4List4moveFT4fromSi2toSi_T_) to move an object from one index to another, which should correspond directly to the indices in the table view you're reordering.

Here's a tutorial you can follow guides you through building a task management app, including support for reordering tasks: https://realm.io/docs/realm-mobile-platform/example-app/cocoa/

Answer (score 0):

A `List` is certainly efficient and clean, though I wasn't sure how I would sync it through a server. So in my case I'm using `orderPosition: Double`, and the value is calculated as the middle of the two existing `orderPosition`s that the object is inserted between. Also keep in mind that you can perform the write without updating the tableView from the notification: `try! list.realm?.commitWrite(withoutNotifying: [notificationToken!])`.

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested, List is the solution. Here is the example to implement the approach on Swift 5:

```swift
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

// The master list of `Item`s stored in realm
class Items: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    let items = List<Item>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

class Item: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
}

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    var items = RealmSwift.List<Item>()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // initialize database
        var itemsData = realm.object(ofType: Items.self, forPrimaryKey: 0)
        if itemsData == nil {
            itemsData = try! realm.write { realm.create(Items.self, value: []) }
        }
        items = itemsData!.items

        // temporarily add new items
        let newItem1 = Item()
        newItem1.name = "Item 1"
        let newItem2 = Item()
        newItem2.name = "Item 2"
        try! realm.write {
            items.append(newItem1)
            items.append(newItem2)
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    ...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        try! items.realm?.write {
            items.move(from: sourceIndexPath.row, to: destinationIndexPath.row)
        }
    }
}
```

You can find example applications for both iOS and macOS in GitHub Repo (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa) under `examples/`, demonstrating how to use many features of Realm like migrations, how to use it with UITableViewControllers, encryption, command-line tools and much more.